# Missing samples of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, sampling

My df:

```
In [163]: df.head()
Out[163]: 
                       x-axis    y-axis    z-axis
time   
2017-07-27 06:23:08 -0.107666 -0.068848  0.963623
2017-07-27 06:23:08 -0.105225 -0.070068  0.963867
.....
```

I set the index as datetime. Since the sampling rate (10 Hz) is not always constant in the dataframe and for some second I have 8 or 9 samples.

1. I would like to specify the milliseconds on my datatime (06:23:08**.100**, 06:23:08**.200**, etc.)
2. I also would like to do interpolation of the missing samples.

Some ideas how to do it in pandas?

Comment: I only see two rows with the same timestamp.  If we were to reindex the dataframe  with a frequency of `100ms` or `10 Hz`, We'd just be lumping all rows with the same second into the corresponding first deci-second.  The remaining 9 deci-seconds would be empty.  Your data must possess information for fractional seconds otherwise this exercise will fail.  Please provide sample data with fractional seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets create some sample data which maybe resembles your data.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

base = datetime.now()
date_list = [base - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 2)]
values = [v for v in range(2)]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date': date_list, 'values': values})

df = df.set_index('Date')
df

                           values
Date    
2017-08-18 20:42:08.563878  0
2017-08-17 20:42:08.563878  1
```

Now we will create another data frame with every 100 milliseconds of datapoint.

```
min_val = df.index.min()
max_val = df.index.max()

all_val = []
while min_val <= max_val:
    all_val.append(min_val)
    min_val += timedelta(milliseconds=100)
# len(all_val) 864001 
df_new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date': all_val})
df_new = df_new.set_index('Date')
```

## lets join both data frame so all missing rows will have index but no values.

```
final_df = df_new.join(df)
final_df

                            values
Date    
2017-08-17 20:42:08.563878  1.0
2017-08-17 20:42:08.663878  NaN
2017-08-17 20:42:08.763878  NaN
2017-08-17 20:42:08.863878  NaN
2017-08-17 20:42:08.963878  NaN
2017-08-17 20:42:09.063878  NaN
2017-08-17 20:42:09.163878  NaN
```

Now interpolate data:

```
df_final.interpolate()

                            values
Date    
2017-08-17 20:42:08.563878  1.000000
2017-08-17 20:42:08.663878  0.999999
2017-08-17 20:42:08.763878  0.999998
2017-08-17 20:42:08.863878  0.999997
2017-08-17 20:42:08.963878  0.999995
2017-08-17 20:42:09.063878  0.999994
2017-08-17 20:42:09.163878  0.999993
2017-08-17 20:42:09.263878  0.999992
```

Some interpolation strategies: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html

UPDATE: As per the discussion in comments:

say our initial data does not have millisecond information.

```
df_new_date_without_miliseconds = df_new['Date']
df_new_date_without_miliseconds[0] # Timestamp('2017-08-17 21:45:49')

max_value_date = df_new_date_without_miliseconds[0]
max_value_miliseconds = df_new_date_without_miliseconds[0]

updated_dates = []
for val in df_new_date_without_miliseconds:
    if val == max_value_date:
        val = max_value_miliseconds + timedelta(milliseconds=100)
        max_value_miliseconds = val
    elif val > max_value_date:
        max_value_date = val + timedelta(milliseconds=0)
        max_value_miliseconds = val
    updated_dates.append(val)

output:

[Timestamp('2017-08-17 21:45:49.100000'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-17 21:45:49.200000'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-17 21:45:49.300000'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-17 21:45:50'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-17 21:45:50.100000'),
```

Assign the new values to the DataFrame

```
df_new['Date'] = updated_dates
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea of interpolation and joining. The problem  with my df is that I have 10 samples for each second, but not the specification of time, so in milliseconds. Therefore, I have 10 data with the same timestamp, which I couldn't be able to join to the new df_new. I think I should first add milliseconds to my original df, before adding it to the df_new. But I don't know how to do it. Any idea?

Comment: you can randomly add 100 *n milliseconds to each datapoint. but that won't give you correct order of data. Point is if your original data doesn't have milliseconds then by generating random milliseconds you are creating wrong data.

Comment: @EmanuelaLiaci updated code to add millisecond information to dataframe.