# Fill missing date record by duplication former date record in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes with discontinues date as follows:

```
Date         Value
2015-10-23   75%
2015-08-25   50%
2015-02-20   30%
```

I want to fill missing data records by duplicating the nearest lower date records to the current date, for example:

```
Date         Value
2017-08-20   75%
...          75% 
2015-10-24   75%
2015-10-23   75%
2015-10-22   50%
...          50%
2015-08-26   50%
2015-08-25   50%
2015-08-24   30%
...          30%
2015-02-21   30%
2015-02-20   30%
```

How could I do that in a simple way ,thanks!

Comment: what is Value mean ? how we calculate it ? what you tried so far ?

Comment: Just follow romain's suggestion I got the required result.

Comment: ok do you have still need solution or your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can simply using `reindex`

```
idx=pd.date_range(start='2015-02-20',end='2015-10-23', freq='D')
df=df.set_index(df.Date,drop=True)
df.reindex(idx).ffill().sort_index(ascending=False).drop('Date',1).reset_index().\
                rename(columns={'index':'Date'})


Out[304]: 
          Date Value
0   2015-10-23   75%
1   2015-10-22   50%
2   2015-10-21   50%
3   2015-10-20   50%
4   2015-10-19   50%
5   2015-10-18   50%
6   2015-10-17   50%
7   2015-10-16   50%
8   2015-10-15   50%
9   2015-10-14   50%
10  2015-10-13   50%
11  2015-10-12   50%
12  2015-10-11   50%
13  2015-10-10   50%
14  2015-10-09   50%
15  2015-10-08   50%
16  2015-10-07   50%
17  2015-10-06   50%
18  2015-10-05   50%
19  2015-10-04   50%
20  2015-10-03   50%
21  2015-10-02   50%
22  2015-10-01   50%
23  2015-09-30   50%
24  2015-09-29   50%
25  2015-09-28   50%
26  2015-09-27   50%
27  2015-09-26   50%
28  2015-09-25   50%
29  2015-09-24   50%
```

Comment: Hi, Wen, thanks for your answer, but when I run an error report "ValueError: labels ['Date'] not contained in axis", I try to google but find no useful hints...

Comment: @Harry do you have columns `Date` ?

Comment: @Harry also , which line give back this error

Comment: yes, I have this columns, but not the same name. the last line give back the error

Comment: @Harry change all Date to you column names

Comment: Thanks，I'll try again

Answer (score 3):

You can simply

- `resample` according to the frequency you want: here day `1D`
- fill missing values according to the method you want: here `pad` that fills values forward, so that the “last known value” is available at every time point.

This can be done in one line of code.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# Test data
zz = """Date         Value
2015-10-23   75%
2015-08-25   50%
2015-02-20   30%
"""     
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(zz), delim_whitespace=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
# Setting date as the index
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# Resampling and filling missing values
df.resample('1D').pad()

#            Value
# Date            
# 2015-02-20   30%
# 2015-02-21   30%
# 2015-02-22   30%
# 2015-02-23   30%
# 2015-02-24   30%
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want, but just one question, how can I duplicate the last date record to upto current day? That is "2017-08-20   75%", I didn't find useful parameter for attribute .resample

Comment: I know, just add one record for current day is OK :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date': ['2015-10-23','2015-08-25', '2015-02-20'],
                             'values': [75,50,30]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df
```

output:

```
    Date    values
0   2015-10-23  75
1   2015-08-25  50
2   2015-02-20  30
```

create another dataframe with all dates present.

```
min_val = df['Date'].min()
max_val = df['Date'].max()

all_val = []
while min_val <= max_val:
    all_val.append(min_val)
    min_val += timedelta(days=1)

df_new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Date': all_val})

df_new
```

output:

```
    Date
0   2015-02-20
1   2015-02-21
2   2015-02-22
```

Then merge the two data frames so that all missing values from original dataframe comes in

```
df_final = df_new.merge(df, on='Date', how='outer')
```

Finally forward fill the dataframe. ie :fill missing data records by duplicate the nearest lower date records to current date

```
df_final.ffill(inplace=True)

df_final

    Date      values
0   2015-02-20  30.0
1   2015-02-21  30.0
2   2015-02-22  30.0
```

I gave a very similar answer a couple of days back here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45759989/3027854

Comment: Thanks, another useful method